# I can move and choose things in my hotbar, but everything has disappeared

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues

I was playing a realm a month ago and everything was fine. However I have this issue now that seems to happen a lot. I wanted to play today, but every time I enter, controls, mobs, players and their gamertags, food bar, hotbar, my doll, my inventory, scoreboard, and even the pause and chat button disappear. I tried reinstalling Minecraft and restarting my device and nothing happened. However, I can still move and choose things in my hot bar but I don't see them.

Note: Minecraft v1.9.0 - Samsung galaxy Tab E

Comment: There is a button on PC that does this but I don't remember which.  So it's a feature not a bug, just find which control toggles it.

Comment: I am on minecraft pocket edition not pc. I mentioned it up.

Answer (score 1):

Found this

https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/minecraft-bedrock-support/2795471-controls-have-disappeared-and-so-has-the-options

There players suggest going in the options -> video settings -> turn off "hide GUI".
I don't have pocket edition to test this.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Click on where the pause button is supposed to be, then settings, video, hide GUI. That will toggle everything on or off